# How to round value of inches in decimal and to create a convert constructor that makes a object form a double?

Tags: c++

I am working on this for my homework assignment that is due tonight. This assignment is split into two parts. First, I have to create a type conversion operator for unsigned int that sets the variable to round value of len_inches in decimal. Second, I have to create a convert constructor so that a length object can be created from a double.

I was able to write up the constructors mostly, but I have not gotten rounding it down for the first part nor initializing feet into inches for the second part right. You can see it in the coding right here.

Edit: I have managed to fix up the problems for the most part which you can see in the code below. However, I still do not know how to make a type conversion operator for unsigned int. It would not compile so I have to use an integer instead of an unsigned integer. However, the assignment requires the type conversion operator be for unsigned int, not regular int.

Length2.cpp

```
#include "Length2.h"  

//*********************************************** 
// Operator double converts Length to a double  *
//***********************************************
Length::operator double() const
{
    return this->len_inches /12 + (this->len_inches %12) / 12.0;
}

//*********************************************** 
// Operator double converts Length to a unsigned int  *
//***********************************************
Length::operator unsigned int() const
{
    return round(this->len_inches / 12 + (this->len_inches % 12) / 12.0);
}

//*********************************************
// Overloaded stream insertion operator <<    *
//*********************************************
ostream &operator<<(ostream& out, Length a)
{
    out << a.getFeet() << " feet, " << a.getInches() << " inches";
    return out;
}
```

Length2.h

```
#pragma once 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Length
{ 
private:
    int len_inches;
public:
    Length(int feet, int inches)
    {
        setLength(feet, inches);
    }
    Length(int inches){ len_inches = inches; }
    Length(double feet){ len_inches = feet * 144; }
    
    int getFeet() const{ return len_inches / 12; }
    int getInches() const { return len_inches % 12; }
    void setLength(int feet, int inches)
    {
        len_inches = 12 *feet + inches;
    }
    // Type conversion operators
    operator double() const;
    operator int() const;
    
    // Overloaded stream output operator
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, Length a);

    //Convert Constructor from double
    Length(double dValue)
    {
        value = dValue;
    }
    double getValue() const { return value; }
};
```

main.cpp

```
// This program demonstrates the type conversion operators for
// the Length class. 
#include "Length2.h"   

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> //fstream, ifstream, ofstream
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   int ui = 0;
    Length distance(4, 6);
    ui = distance;
    cout << ui << " feet." << endl;

    Length distance1(4.5);
    double ui2 = -1;
    ui2 = distance1;
    cout << ui2 << " inches." << endl;


   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The requirements of this program are exceptionally unclear. Why are you storing both a `double` and `int` in the class? What is `value` supposed to represent? What intrinsic units should `Length` represent? Your conversion operators provide _feet_. If a `double` is supposed to represent feet and an integer represents inches (terrible idea, btw) then you can simply initialize `len_inches = static_cast<int>(dValue * 12.0);` -- this will truncate. If you want to round the result, use `std::round`.

Comment: Side note: never write the same code twice; if you need to change it there’s a good chance that you’ll overlook one of them. The two conversion operators in `Length` should be rewritten so that th conversion code only occurs in one place.

Answer (score 1):

Storing two versions of the same length is problematic. Yet, in the OP, member variables `len_inches` and `value` do just that. With *duplicate data*, you have the constant concern that the two values may not correspond to the same length. Every time you update one, you have to remember to update the other. It is likely that class `Length` is supposed to store only one of them, and rely on conversion functions or operators when the other is needed.

Furthermore, nothing in the OP makes it clear what units are being used by member variable `value`. Are they decimal inches, decimal feet, or something else? In the following, I assume that lengths of type `double` are measured in decimal feet. Those are the units used by `operator double` in the OP.

I also assume, based on the need for rounding described in the OP, that lengths are supposed to be stored internally in inches. My guess is that the converting constructor for type `double` is supposed to round to the nearest inch, and that class `Length` stores the rounded value as an `int`.

##### Rounding

> How to round a value of inches in decimal, and to create a converting constructor that makes an object from a double?

This is a three-step process. As state above, I will assume that the value of type `double` is measured in decimal feet, and that the value of type `int` is measured in inches.

1. Multiply the `double` by `12.0`. This converts it to decimal inches.
2. Call [`std::round`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) to do the rounding.
3. Use `static_cast` to convert the result to type `int`.

`std::round` is a library function from header `<cmath>`. It rounds its floating point argument to the nearest whole number, without changing its type. When the argument is exactly halfway between two whole numbers, `std::round` systematically "rounds up", i.e., it rounds toward the value that is largest in absolute value. For positive arguments, this means rounding up; for negative arguments, down (to the next lower whole number).

```cpp
// main.cpp
// Demonstrate how `std::round` works.
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
    double x{ 0.5 };
    auto pos{ std::round(x) };
    auto neg{ std::round(-x) };
    std::cout << std::format(
        "Variable `pos`"
        "\n  type  : {}"  // double
        "\n  value : {}"  // 1.0
        "\n"
        "\nVariable `neg`"
        "\n  type  : {}"  // double
        "\n  value : {}"  // -1.0
        "\n\n"
        , typeid(pos).name()
        , pos
        , typeid(neg).name()
        , neg
    );
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Variable `pos`
  type  : double
  value : 1

Variable `neg`
  type  : double
  value : -1
```

To convert the result to type `int` requires a `static_cast`.

```cpp
// main.cpp
// Demonstrate `std::round` with `static_cast`.
#include <format>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main()
{
    double x{ 0.5 };
    auto pos{ static_cast<int>(std::round(x)) };
    auto neg{ static_cast<int>(std::round(-x)) };
    std::cout << std::format(
        "Variable `pos`"
        "\n  type  : {}"  // int
        "\n  value : {}"  // 1
        "\n"
        "\nVariable `neg`"
        "\n  type  : {}"  // int
        "\n  value : {}"  // -1
        "\n\n"
        , typeid(pos).name()
        , pos
        , typeid(neg).name()
        , neg
    );
    return 0;
}
// end file: main.cpp
```

Output:

```
Variable `pos`
  type  : int
  value : 1

Variable `neg`
  type  : int
  value : -1
```

In short, you can get the result you require like this:

```cpp
double x = 42.5;  // or any other value measured in decimal feet
int i;
i = static_cast<int>(std::round(12.0 * x));
```

How do you adapt this for a constructor? I will leave that up to you! (*Hint:* `x` should be the parameter of the constructor, while `i` should be the member variable.)

##### Conversion operator for `unsigned int`

> I still do not know how to make a type conversion operator for unsigned int.

The short answer is use `static_cast`.

```cpp
int i = 42;  // or any other value
unsigned int u;
u = static_cast<unsigned int>(i);
```

Interestingly, the [implicit type conversions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_conversions) that are part of C++ make the cast optional.

```cpp
// Direct assignment works just as well.
u = i;
```

If the return type of a function is `unsigned int`, you can return a value of type `int` (with or without using `static_cast`). The returned value will have type `unsigned int`.

For what it's worth, my own preference is to document type conversions, by using `static_cast`.

Once again, I will leave it to you to adapt this for your homework assignment.